# Simple Bash Online-time-counting Script for Teamspeak 3 via log?

Tags: bash, shell, variables, teamspeak

So, I'm trying to count the time a user has been online on a Teamspeak 3 server via log.
The log format is something like

`2015-10-14 23:30:29.676932|INFO    |VirtualServerBase|  1| client connected 'clientX'(id:XY) from IPx.IPx.IPx.IPx:PortX
2015-10-15 00:12:45.870381|INFO    |VirtualServerBase|  1| client disconnected 'clientX'(id:XY) reason 'reasonmsg=leave'`.

I can of course use `grep "client connected \|client disconnected"` to filter out the other entries and add `| grep "(id:XY)"` to only see user XY.
If i use `| cut -c 1-16` to only see the time and date and filter out everything unnecessary.

The resulting command is `cat *.log | grep "client connected\|client disconnected" | cut -c 1-16`.
Afterwards, the output looks like this:

`2015-10-02 14:12
2015-10-02 14:17
2015-10-06 14:18
2015-10-06 15:27`

The question is: how do I count the times between connects and disconnects and add them up inside a shell-script?

Comment: More complex than you think, you have to deal with differents users If you want to get a connection time...

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the best way is to get an output like :

```
CLIENTID1 YYYY-MM-DD connect
CLIENTID2 YYYY-MM-DD connect
CLIENTID3 YYYY-MM-DD connect
CLIENTID1 YYYY-MM-DD disconnect
```

Here is a first command line to get theses lines (assuming that `(id:XY)` is an uniq client id) :

```
sed 's/^\(.*:[0-9][0-9]\).* \(dis\)\?connected.*(id:\([^)]*\)).*$/\3 \1 \2connected/'
```

Then for each `connect` line you have to find the disconnect one using `CLIENTID`. Retrieving the dates (trivial) you can get their diff (already discussed on SO, you can use `date`).